# How to insert date+id into SQL

Tags: php, codeigniter

**How to insert date+id into SQL**

like this 20181207001

2018-12-07 is date

001 is id

I want the current date and ID. Add to database By pulling out the show.
thank for help.

```
function GenIDInv()
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->db->select('n_id');
    $CI->db->from('notification_name');
    $CI->db->order_by("n_id", "desc");
    $query = $CI->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();
    if(!empty($result)){
        $result = $result->n_id;
        $rid = substr($result,1,4);
        $id =  $rid+1;
        if($id<=9) {
            $NewID = "00$id";
        } else if($id<=99) {
            $NewID ="0$id";
        } else if($id<=999) {
            $NewID ="$id";
        } else {
            $NewID = $id;
        }
        return $NewID;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
echo date('Ymd') . sprintf("%'.03d\n", 1);
```

`date('Ymd')` will return the date in required format.

`sprintf()` will return a string as needed. and the concatenate them accordingly.

**Output**

```
20181207001
```

[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)